# Line Element on a Sin Function

Tags: multivariable-calculus, solution-verification, line-integrals

Maybe this is better suited for Physics Exchange, but I have been self studying line elements and I wanted to check my understanding against the community. I tried to derive the line element for some f(x,y):

Consider the function of $y = 3\sin(x)$, I parameterized using $x=(t)$

$$ y = 3\sin(x) \to x=(t), y=3\sin(t) $$

Plugging this into arc length I get:

$$ S  = \int_{0}^{1}\sqrt{(1)^2+(3\cos(x))^2} \,dt $$

From that I got the line element: $$ ds^2 = (1 + 9\cos^2(x))dx^2 $$

Is this right, or am I completely wrong here???

Comment: $$ds^2 = dx^2 + dy^2 = \left(\frac{dx}{dt}\right)^2dt^2 +  \left(\frac{dy}{dt}\right)^2dt^2$$ Since $t$ is the independent variable here, not $x$, your answer should be $$ds^2 = (1+9\cos^2 t)dt^2$$

Comment: @PaulSinclair Ahh ok, so make sure to use the parameter variable, but other than that this is the correct line element for the curve?

Comment: I would not have said it should be your answer if it were not correct. Since $x = t, \frac{dx}{dt} = 1$, Since $y = 3\sin t, \frac{dy}{dt} = 3\cos t$. So $$d^2s = 1^2dt^2 + (3\cos t)^2dt^2 = (1 + 9\cos^2 t)dt^2$$This is how one normally derives it - not by using an integral expression that was essentially proved from this differential line element.

Comment: @PaulSinclair The way my math professor explained it to me was that the line element is kind of like a short hand for (or maybe derived from) the arc length equation, so I wanted to try and work from first steps. But is that just making it more complicated?

Comment: Both your professor and I are simplifying a subject with a complicated history, in order to get basic concepts across without hassling over details. The integral expression and the differential expression are equivalent. But the integral is rigorous at a Calc I level, while differentials are famous for being hard to define rigorously. However, they are more intuitive, and physicists are not concerned about the mathematical concept of rigor (and have good reasons for that attitude). Thus you will usually see line elements developed using differentials in physics texts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As discussed in the comments with @PaulSinclair the original line element I posted is close, but not quite correct. $ dx^2 $ should be $ dt^2$ , and therefore the correct line element should be:

$$ ds^2 = (1 + 9\cos^2 t)dt^2 $$